# Show that $\dim V^{G} = 1/|G| \sum_{g \in G} \chi_{T} (g). $

Tags: representation-theory

Let $T$ be a complex linear representation of the group $G$ in a space $V$

Show that $\dim V^{G} = 1/|G| \sum_{g \in G} \chi_{T} (g).$

If I know the definition of $V^G$ from this corollary:

[image]

Which means like the elements of $V_{k}$ on which $T_{k}(h)$ is the trivial representation for all $h \in H.$

And we know the definition of $\chi_{T}$ from the following corollary:

[image]

But then I can not see how the $\dim V^G$ will be equal this, could anyone explain this for me please?

Comment: The direct way is to let $S(x)v = \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} T(g)v$ then $S$ is the projection of $V$ onto $V^G$ as well as the representation of $G$ on $V^G$ and $\dim(V^G) = tr(S(1))$

Comment: Could you provide more details please? why $\dim (V^G) = tr (S(1))$?@reuns

Comment: Because $S(1)$ is a projection matrix. In the correct basis $S(1)(u,w) = u$.